# changing form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I want to change form post data before send. i use some java script code to get some user inputs and want to attach those to request post data.
I wanna a normal post that cause to display result as a an HTML page.
its may be useful that i linked JQuery and can use its functions.
Thanks very much!

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. Also, you probably want to show some code

Comment: When user click submit button, value of input elements of form would be sent to server, i want to change this data in client before sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onSubmit` event as shown below -

```
<form action="test.php" name="testform" onSubmit="return TestDataCheck()" >
<input type="text" value="hello" name="testinput" />
<form>
```

Define a function as shown below -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestDataCheck(){

//Here do whatever you want to do with the form or it's values.
//I am changing the value of input field in the form for your reference in same way you
//can change any elements value.

$('input[name="testinput"]').val("bye");

return true.

}
</script>
```

Comment: The question is that, how can change the form data, i should replace the comment with what? The question is about the code that i can write in TestDataCheck!

Comment: For your reference i have changed the value of the input field in the form in my example. In same way you can change any field's value.

Comment: If you want specific solution then please post you html form and values to be replaced.

Comment: i figure out! i can add some hidden input to form without affecting UI,Thanks any way!

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<form action="test.php" name="testform" id="testForm">
<input type="text" value="hello" name="testinput" />
<form>
```

**javascript**

```
//handle form submit
   jQuery("#testForm").submit(function(e){

      //prevent default action
      e.preventDefault; 

     //get form
     var _data=jQuery("#testForm").serialize();

     //add custom props
     _data['customProp1']='customValue1';
     _data['customProp2']='customValue2';

     //now just submit form or call ajax

    });
```